# PhpStorm Dumb to file (CSV) Import back gives 1:5: conversion failed: "" to datetime

Tags: phpstorm, export-to-csv, datagrip, import-csv

I exported my table to CSV and now need to import back and my column `created` and `modified` has a type `timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and is failing.

PhpStorm export as `datetime` e.g: `2019-07-29 15:51:12` import fails obviously as the type is different!

PHPStorm import has preview before import:
[image]

[image]
[image]
Is there a way to export/import to CSV as `timestamp` ?

Comment: If you mean MySQL (you don't really say), the input/output format for both column types is identical so the problem would be somewhere else. The error message suggests you actually have an empty string.

Comment: "import fails obviously as the type is different" What? That looks right format for MySQL to me. Is this problem fixed? If not u need to clarify what exactly is going on and/or NOT going on.

Comment: @BeNice I've added screen shoots of the table column When I export to CSV is fine if I try to rein-port the same CSV if fails with the error

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  I know right the error suggested that `created` or `modified` column is empty but in fact it isn't it might be a Bug hence I and stuck!